# How to check if a file equals a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am a novice with Python I suppose, and I was wondering if there was a way to read a file and then check if user's input equalled that file's text.

I've been trying to create a password program without having to show the password/variable in the program. If there's another way to do this without doing `.read()` and things (if they don't work) then I would be happy to hear those suggestions!

Comment: This is a very broad question, what about security, are you going to store the passwords in plain text?

Comment: You can't read a file without `.read()`-ing it - so I'm not sure what you are asking.  Please edit the question and add the code that didn't work (as you said, _without doing `.read()`_ so I'm assuming something was written that uses `.read()` that didn't work).

Comment: OP said if `.read()` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you specifically don't want to use `.read()`, and what you mean by "without having to show the password/variable"?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham  Yeah, this is just for fun and seeing how it works, so I'm just using plain text.

Comment: @Cyphase, the way I had to write the program before was assigning the password to a variable inside the program, which as you can tell doesn't do much good. It works, but you can just look in the script and find the password.

Comment: Ah, I see; in that case, my answer should work for you. But as @PadraicCunningham commented here and on my answer, storing passwords in plaintext is a **bad** idea. I understand this is just for learning; just be sure you're not using this to "learn" how to store passwords :).

Comment: @Cyphase Okay, thanks for your help and speedy responses!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
# The path to the file
filepath = 'thefile.txt'

# This is how you should open files
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    # Get the entire contents of the file
    file_contents = f.read()

    # Remove any whitespace at the end, e.g. a newline
    file_contents = file_contents.strip()

# Get the user's input
user_input = input('Enter input: ')

if user_input == file_contents:
    print('Match!')
else:
    print('No match.')
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, _If there's another way to do this without doing .read() and things_ **(if they don't work)** _then I would be happy to hear those suggestions!_

Comment: *without having to show the password/variable in the program.*

Comment: what do you think happens with `input('Enter input: ')`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, in Python 3.4, as the question is tagged, it gets a string from stdin.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I see your point; it's not clear if that's what the OP meant, but it certainly might be. You know, you could have just said, "The OP doesn't want the password to be visible when it's entered", and that would have been clear. I realize I also could have asked for clarification instead of doing more quoting, but it was kind of amusing :).

Comment: Just checking; was your first comment related to not showing the password?

Comment: The *without having to show the password/variable in the program.*, I voted to close the question because there is no one answer to the question, storing passwords in plain text and echoing the password is laos probably a very bad idea.